# Prove or disprove that the set of probabilities $\{p \in \Delta^n \mid \mbox{Var}(X) \leq \alpha\}$ is a convex set.

Tags: statistics, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, variance

Prove or disprove that the set $$S:= \left\{p \in \Delta^n \mid \mbox{Var}(X) \leq \alpha \right\}$$ is convex. $p \in \Delta^n$ denotes that $p$ is a probability distribution (i.e., belongs to the probability simplex). $X$ is a random variable such that $p(X = a_i) = p_i$, where $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_n\in \mathbb{R}$.

<sub>The question was taken from the exercise 2.15 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook)</sub>

---

My current attempts are to pick two arbitrary points from $S$ and show that the convex combination stays in $S$. I realized that I could use the formula $\mbox{Var}(X) = E[(X - E(X))^2]$, but I don't know how to proceed because the $(\cdot)^2$ in the variance prevents me from distributing the convex combination inside $(\cdot)^2$. Also, $E(X)$ in $X - E(X)$ depends on the probability distribution to provide.

Could anyone provide some pointers? I have been stuck for two days.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check whether the variance is a convex function of $X$.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused about why "variance" could/couldn't be a convex function of $X$. In particular, proving a function is convex often requires us to take two points on the convex function and show that the convex combination of the two points satisfies the Jenson's Inequality, but $X$ is a random variable, how could we take two points?

Comment: You should check whether $\mathbf{var}(X)$ is convex in $p$. A convex _function_ has sublevel sets which are convex _sets_. In this case your set is in terms of $p$ so you need to check whether variance is a convex function of $p$

Comment: @Casey Convexity of sublevel sets is a necessery condition of convexity. The functions for which such sets are convex are called quasi-convex.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check, for some nontrivial set of $a_i$, and $\alpha=0$, whether the vertices of $\Delta^n$ lie in $S$?

Answer (score 0):

To get an intuitive feel, maybe think about some distributions that you know the variance of (i.e. if $X$ is Bernoulli then $\mathbf{var}(X)= p(1-p)$) then check if it's convex. If you find one counter example then you're done. If the statement is true this won't prove it but the intuition might help